# How to prove that $\int\limits_0^{\pi} e^{\sin^2(x)}dx > {3\over2}\pi$?

Tags: definite-integrals, integral-inequality

How to prove that $\int\limits_0^{\pi} e^{\sin^2(x)}\ dx > {3 \over 2}\pi$?

Comment: Could you please edit the question, the math notations are not showing.

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would down-vote this question. It's perfect fine and compiles with the requirements of the page.

Comment: @DavidG Hover your cursor over the voting arrows... "This question (shows / does not show any) research effort".

Comment: @DavidG Go to [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and report back to us in which ways this question satisfies *any* of the criteria.  This is a problem statement question, essentially expecting answerers to do this users work for them.  Hence the downvote, hence the close votes.  This site is not a "do my work/proof for me" service.

Comment: @amWhy - will do. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 7):

Use the inequality $e^t\ge 1+t$, valid for all $t$, to get:
$$
\int_0^\pi e^{\sin^2x}dx\ge\int_0^\pi(1+\sin^2x)dx=\int_0^\pi\left(\frac32 + \frac12\cos 2x\right)\,dx
$$
You should be able to take it from here. The inequality is in fact strict, because the difference $e^{\sin^2x}-(1+\sin^2x)$ is continuous, non-negative and not identically zero.

Comment: I've taken and it equals to $int_0^\pi(1+\sin^2x)dx = {3\over2}\pi$ But is it really right to use $e^t\ge 1+t$?

Comment: $$e^t > 1+t$$ is true for all nonzero real numbers, hence it is not necessary to use the second term of Taylor expansion.

Comment: got it, thank you!

Comment: @ArseniyBakaev The inequality $e^t\ge 1+t$ is easily proven: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330815/215011

Comment: @Crostul Right, and the justification that $\int_0^\pi \sin^4 (x) dx>0$ will equally apply to $\int_0^\pi e^{\sin^2x}dx > \int_0^\pi (1+\sin^2x)dx$.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use Taylor expansion: $e^{\sin^2(x)}=1+\sin^2(x)+\sin^4(x)/2+...$ and integrate it from $0$ to $\pi$

$\int_0^\pi(1+\sin^2(x)+(\sin^4(x))/2)dx=(27\pi)/16 ≈ 5.3014 > 3\pi/2$

Comment: Why post this, which copies the idea of a previous answer, only more clumsily?

Answer (score -2):

The integral is a Bessel function:

$$\sqrt{e} \pi  I_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

which has numerical value $5.50843$, which is indeed less than $3 \pi/2$.  This, it would seem, answers the question completely in a principled, and correct manner.  One might try any number of other techniques, but I cannot see how any could be better than *solving* the integral exactly.

Comment: Is it possible to compare without Bessel function?

Comment: The only other way to compare would be a *numerical* integration.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Bessel function does the trick, but in order to just find a soft result, you can go by the ML inequality as elaborated below.

Comment: "The only other way to compare would be a numerical integration" Not true.